# Query hive table with Spark

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, hive

I am newbie to Apache Hive and Spark.  I have some existing Hive tables sitting on my Hadoop server that I can run some HQL commands and get what I want out of the table using hive or beeline, e.g, selecting first 5 rows of my table.  Instead of that I want to use Spark to achieve the same goal.  My Spark version on server is 1.6.3.

Using below code (I replace my database name and table with **database** and **table**):

```
sc = SparkContext(conf = config)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

query = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from database.table LIMIT 5").collect())
df = query.toPandas()
df.show()
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined after inferring.  
Error:root: An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (1, 0))
```

However, I can use beeline with same query and see the results.

After a day of googling and searching I modified the code as:

```
table_ccx = sqlContext.table("database.table")
table_ccx.registerTemplate("temp")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM temp LIMIT 5").show()
```

Now the error is gone but all the row values are null except one or two dates and column names.

I also tried

```
table_ccx.refreshTable("database.table")
```

and it did not help.  Is there a setting or configuration that I need to ask my IT team to do? I appreciate any help.

**EDIT**: Having said that, my python code is working for some of the table on Hadoop.  Do not know the problem is because of some entries on table or not? If yes, then how come the corresponding beeline/Hive command is working?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but `sqlContext.createDataFrame(sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from database.table LIMIT 5").collect())` is **really** not necessary. `sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from database.table LIMIT 5")` will do.

Comment: Looks like the table content are unreadable, probably for some mismatching configurations. Can you share the `CREATE` statement for that table? You can show it by running `SHOW CREATE TABLE database.table`.

Comment: You are correct.  I did not need the sqlContext.createDataFrame.  This sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from database.table LIMIT 5")  will  fix the issue.

Comment: Shall I propose it as an answer?

Comment: query = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from database.table LIMIT 5") is the Spark DataFrame and there is no need for create a DataFrame out of it.  So if I want the Pandas DataFrame out of it then query.toPandas() will create it.  Thanks a lot @stefanobaghino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it came out in the comments, straightening up the code a little bit makes the thing work.

The problem lies on this line of code:

```
query = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from database.table LIMIT 5").collect())
```

What you are doing here is:

- asking Spark to query the data source (which creates a `DataFrame`)
- `collect` everything on the driver as a local collection
- parallelize the local collection on Spark with `createDataFrame`

In general the approach *should* work, although it's evidently unnecessarily convoluted.

The following will do:

```
query = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from database.table LIMIT 5")
```

I'm not entirely sure of why the thing breaks your code, but still it does (as it came out in the comments) and it also improves it.

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested, however,  now all the entries are None in Pandas DataFrame and I think the reason is that the Spark DataFrame schema thinks the column should be string and I have integers so it changes everything to None.  Maybe I need to change the Schema somehow and then try it.  Does it make sense what I am saying?

Comment: query.schema --> output: StructType(List(StructField(*****,StringType, true))) and query.show(20) shows everything as null.  So for whatever reason it changes everything to null.

Comment: I think I found the Solution:  For whatever reason when I use Spark 2.1, the entries get populated.